# ReactQuery refetch on window focus

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Every time I focus my window, my query refetchs. Is a query that store the session so shouldn't be needed to do this every time, because cause that a new token is asked to the backend:

```js
export function useSession() {
    return useQuery(['session', 'get'], getSession)
}
```

And on my `Ap.js`:

```js
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const { mutate: login } = useLogin();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (session?.username === null) {
            login({ username: "lime-app", password: "generic" });
        }
    }, [session]);
```

Every time that I focus the page again (also from browser developer tools to the webpage), the session is undefined, so it do the login again.

I tried to add `refetchOnMount: false,` and `refetchOnWindowFocus: false,` on my `QueryClient` without success.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging for a lot I realized that the query data was on `stale` state always. Reading the [docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/important-defaults):

> Query instances via useQuery or useInfiniteQuery by default consider cached data as stale.

Which implies that every time it can, it try to refetch. Finally, reading the docs, I found that the only thing I have to add to my query is an option to disable the stale time: `{staleTime: Infinity}` :

```
export function useSession() {
    return useQuery(['session', 'get'], getSession, {staleTime: Infinity})
}
```

On this way it won't refetch anymore